# ASP.net Identity 2.0 Membership with VB , not C#

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, azure

I have an existing VB.net webforms website. I need to move it off godaddy. It uses older asp membership. I want to use Identity 2.0 so that I can use Azure. There are many [tutorials](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/features-api/account-confirmation-and-password-recovery-with-aspnet-identity#createMvc) for migrating, but all are c#. I simply do not have the time to convert to c#. I have made basic membership work, but I need to add password recovery (so I need email on signup). Again, the instructions are all c#, and it is not just a case of translating c# to VB.net (the project files are different. So, my question is: is it even possible to use password recovery/reset with vb.net on Identity 2.0? Or, should I continue using my current sql server membership for authenticating, then store user data on a faster sql like azure?
Or is there another option?

Comment: It is all .Net language, so the API are the same, you'll need to "translate" c# to vb.net and there are many converters, for example http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/ or http://converter.telerik.com/

Comment: @trailmax OP said : "*and it is not just a case of translating c# to VB.net (the project files are different)*". He already knows he can translate using some websites.

Comment: re. Translating. In the tutorial example, there are .cs files that do not exist in VB version of the same project. Sorry if I am missing something, I am a hobbyist at best

Comment: @Sifu sure, the project files will be different. Translation is not going to be error-free and easy, but it do most of the work. And looking on C# API it is easy enough to apply the same methods in VB, even without using the converters.

Comment: Thanks all. I have stumbled my way to a point where the signup works with email. The reg asks for security questions, but the emailing the user is not working. I will keep plugging away--the c# procedures are definitely different. Too bad there is not a sample vb project with working email pass recovery. I am going to see if I can translate this: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/gallery/store/sendgrid/sendgrid-azure/ I guess VB is not all that supported anymore?

Comment: @Cory use something like http://converter.telerik.com/ to batch convert most of it. VB is and will always be supported, it has the same base language (.net). All you need to do after is fix the remaining bugs.

Comment: Voting to close - I asked this long ago-this Visual Studio 2013, this is a non-issue